# Where to find debug options - step through, step over, resume?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am using the eclipse IDE.

Here is what I currently see [image]

As you can tell, I m in the debug perspective and currently debugging a piece of code(stop button enabled at bottom right corner). Usually when I am in debug perspective in eclipse, I see icons for resuming/pausing, stopping, step over, and step into. I don't what I did to make those icons disappear. Does anyone know how to restore these icons? I tried window -> reset perspective, which gave me

[image]

but clicking yes didn't make those icons reappear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icons are hidden. You can try to show them from [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm):

> 1. Switch to the perspective that you want to configure.
> 2. Select command link Window > Customize Perspective....
> 3. Open the Menu Visibility or Tool Bar Visibility tab.
> 4. Find the item you want to hide. You can do this two ways:
>
>    - Expand the menu or toolbar hierarchy to find the item you want to hide.
>    - Click the Filter by command group check box to see a list of command groups which contribute items, and choose the command group the item you wish to hide. Then navigate to the item in the hierarchy in the Structure tree.
> 5. Hover over the item to get additional information:
>
>    - a description of what the item does
>    - the name of the command group which contributes the item (click the link in this item to switch to the Command Groups Availability tab with the appropriate command group selected).
>    - any key bindings associated with the command the item performs (click the link in this item to open the Keys page of the Preferences dialog with the command selected, if possible).
>    - if the item is dynamic, a preview of its current appearance (dynamic items are listed as [Dynamic]).
> 6. Check the check box next to the item. Check a menu to unhide all its children.
> 7. Click OK to cause the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to johndaw16's answer, I realized that indeed, these icons were hidden. If anyone is having a similar issue, what I did was I clicked on [image]

and selected "Show Debug Toolbar"